scope.joinUtil is not working for nested StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure
On Windows 11, Java 22, preview enabled, I am trying to use (JEP 453)'s joinUntil functionality to limit execution duration.
However, I am not able to use it in a nested way. The execution is not stopping even though I used scope.joinUntil.
Could you help me figure it out what is wrong with the code? I don't want to use it only in my main function, but also in my sub projects.
Project code: github
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... s) {
        nestedTest_pureJava(
            Duration.ofSeconds(8),
            Duration.ofSeconds(5),
            5
        );
    }

    private static void nestedTest_pureJava(Duration untilTimeout, Duration workLoad, int nestedId) {
        if (nestedId < 0) {
            out.println("nestedTest_pureJava -> skip -> " + nestedId);
            return;
        }
        out.println("nestedTest_pureJava -> begin -> " + nestedId);
        try (var scope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure()) {
            scope.fork(() -> {
                Thread.sleep(workLoad);
                return null;
            });
            scope.joinUntil(Instant.now().plusSeconds(untilTimeout.getSeconds()));
            scope.throwIfFailed();
            nestedTest_pureJava(untilTimeout, workLoad, nestedId - 1);
        } catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        out.println("nestedTest_pureJava -> end -> " + nestedId);
    }
    
}

Output:
nestedTest_pureJava -> begin -> 5
nestedTest_pureJava -> begin -> 4
nestedTest_pureJava -> begin -> 3
nestedTest_pureJava -> begin -> 2
nestedTest_pureJava -> begin -> 1
nestedTest_pureJava -> begin -> 0
nestedTest_pureJava -> skip -> -1
nestedTest_pureJava -> end -> 0
nestedTest_pureJava -> end -> 1
nestedTest_pureJava -> end -> 2
nestedTest_pureJava -> end -> 3
nestedTest_pureJava -> end -> 4
nestedTest_pureJava -> end -> 5

As I am catching the TimeoutException, I have tried to shutdown the scope, but the problem still persists.
private static void nestedTest_pureJava(Duration untilTimeout, Duration workLoad, int nestedId) {
    if (nestedId < 0) {
        out.println("nestedTest_pureJava -> skip -> " + nestedId);
        return;
    }
    out.println("nestedTest_pureJava -> begin -> " + nestedId);
    var scope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure();
    try {
        scope.fork(() -> {
            Thread.sleep(workLoad);
            return null;
        });
        scope.joinUntil(Instant.now().plusSeconds(untilTimeout.getSeconds()));
        scope.throwIfFailed();
        nestedTest_pureJava(untilTimeout, workLoad, nestedId - 1);
    } catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException | ExecutionException e) {
        if (e instanceof TimeoutException) {
            scope.shutdown();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        scope.close();
    }
    out.println("nestedTest_pureJava -> end -> " + nestedId);
}


Rewriting the example would clarify the question further. From what I can infer now, you wouldn't really be performing a nested operation, since there is a timeout of 8s at servlet, you would mostly expect the downstream calls to complete before

I don’t understand your expectation. Your first code example contains an ordinary recursive invocation of nestedTest_pureJava. There is nothing related to the StructuredTaskScope nor its timeout in this recursive invocations. Of course, they will always run to completion. It’s ordinary, non-asynchronous code.

@Holge   In my messy production code, I could use StructuredTaskScope on main servlet. But when I try to use it on library projects, the misleading exceptions were thrown. So I had to put it on a test. I tried to understand the capability of JDK (is there a limit how deep I can go or not). That is why I put it on a recursive function to test the dept limit.

Your last code example does not have such a recursive call but an asynchronous call. So, of course, an ordinary recursive call behaves differently than an asynchronous call. But then, what is your question?

By the way, your last comment is the first time you mention that “misleading exceptions were thrown” somewhere. If you want to solve that problem, you should open a question about that problem. Worth reading What is the XY problem?

In your first example, the code forks a 5 second job, waits for it up to eight seconds, then invokes itself recursively. Since the job has completed way before the timeout, the entire operation is as good as sequential code, like foo() { sleep(5s); foo(); } This is not about “not respecting joinUntil”, the recursion and the joinUntil are entirely unrelated. In the last example, an asynchronous job containing an invocation of the method is forked, then joinUntil is invoked for that job. So the timeout is about the asynchronous operation and applies if the asych invocation takes too long

@Holger I see now. In the first part of the question, the recursion occures not inside 'scope.fork(...). As u said the first part of the question is just sequencial code.

As a side note, you could limit the execution time of a single threaded recursion too, if you pass down a deadline Instant instead of a timeout Duration. But since your question is actually about the StructuredTaskScope, the solution is to have the invocation inside the asynchronous operation.

As Holger already answered the recursive-code should be inside
'scope.fork(...)'
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... s) {
        nestedTest_pureJava(
            Duration.ofSeconds(8),
            Duration.ofSeconds(5),
            5
        );
    }

    private static void nestedTest_pureJava(Duration untilTimeout, Duration workLoad, int nestedId) {
        if (nestedId < 0) {
            out.println("nestedTest_pureJava -> skip -> " + nestedId);
            return;
        }
        out.println("nestedTest_pureJava -> begin -> " + nestedId);
        var scope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure();
        try {
            scope.fork(() -> {
                Thread.sleep(workLoad);
                nestedTest_pureJava(untilTimeout, workLoad, nestedId - 1);
                return null;
            });
            scope.joinUntil(Instant.now().plusSeconds(untilTimeout.getSeconds()));
            scope.throwIfFailed();

        } catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException | ExecutionException e) {
            if (e instanceof InterruptedException) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            if (e instanceof TimeoutException) {
                scope.shutdown();
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            scope.close();
        }
        out.println("nestedTest_pureJava -> end -> " + nestedId);
    }
}


Nice quiz, Tugalsan lol  At first I was unsure what was it mainly about and probably even @Holger was. You should have clarified what thread exactly you expected to timeout. :) And although the issue is unrelated to Structured Concurrency and can be reproduced with plain Threads, both question and answer are great :+1:
